# geodesic curvature about boundary of geodesic disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M^2$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, choose a point $x\in M^2$, consider the geodesic disc $D_r(x)$. Why do we have following equality?
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\int_{\partial D_t}1 \ ds)=\int_{\partial D_t}k_g\ ds$$
where $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature of $\partial D_t$.

Comment: Have you seen a first-variation-of-arclength computation that shows that geodesics are locally length-minimizing? This is the same computation.

Comment: Thanks @ Ted Shifrin, I think I get it now.